# foreach ($delete_addresses[$key] value failure with imap_delete()

Tags: php, imap

In below example there is an array $delete_addresses filled with email-addresses. The print_r() show all correct.
But within the foreach I do something wrong and do not get the $key number needed for the imap_delete).
I get this not saying a lot error message:
Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /home/deb96951n2/domains/domain.nl/public_html/wp-admin/email_handlers/bouncehandler.php on line 75

Does someone of you with more experience then me can tell me what I do wrong and how to correct it? Imap is not my daily work.

```
$delete_addresses = array();
$bouncecounter = 0;
$deletecounter = 0;
for ($n=1;$n<=$num_msgs;$n++) {
  $bounce = imap_fetchheader($conn, $n).imap_body($conn, $n); //entire message
  $multiArray = $bouncehandler->get_the_facts($bounce);

if (!empty($multiArray[0]['action']) && !empty($multiArray[0]['status']) && !empty($multiArray[0]['recipient']) ) {
        echo $multiArray[0]['action'].'= '.$multiArray[0]['status'].'::'.$multiArray[0]['recipient'].'<br>';
        $delete_addresses[] = $multiArray[0]['recipient'];

  if ($multiArray[0]['action'] == 'failed') {
            $result = mysqli_query($db, "UPDATE wp_mm_external_emails set deleted = 1 WHERE email = '".$multiArray[0]['recipient']."' ");

  } //if delivery failed        
        $deletecounter++;   
} //if passed parsing as bounce
        $bouncecounter++ ;
} //for loop

  foreach ($delete_addresses as $key => $value) { //trim($key) is email address, $value is number of failures

if ($value>=$delete) {      

/*
do whatever you need to do here, e.g. unsubscribe email address
*/
# mark for deletion
        print_r($delete_addresses[$key]);
    foreach ($delete_addresses[$key] as $delnum) imap_delete($conn, $delnum);

} //if failed more than $delete times
```

} //foreach

Comment: Is `$delete_addresses[$key]` is an array? what it prints on `print_r`?

Comment: yes see top of code: $delete_addresses = array(); and it is filled with this: $delete_addresses[] = $multiArray[0]['recipient']; see code
print_r result: Array ( [0] => info@afasdf.nl [1] => info@vvvvv-it.nl [2] => info@cccccccc.nl [3]

Comment: `foreach ($delete_addresses[$key] as $delnum) imap_delete($conn, $delnum);` replace this line with `imap_delete($conn, $delete_addresses[$key]);`, In this line `$delete_addresses[$key]` is not an array.

Comment: Thanks, but is there an option to control the output of this imap_delete(). So I can see that indeed some bounces are deleted from the imap?